# Looking for unusual template engine for massive data generation

Tags: java, python, bigdata, generator, template-engine

I am looking for template data generator which will generate all the combinations of my input template like:

```
Given: template engine ( any — function to select "one of ..." )
Input: [% any('Hi', 'Hello') %] human [% any('!', '?') %] 
Output:
> Hi human !
> Hello human !
> Hi human ?
> Hello human ?
```

Could you advise any?

- It must be deterministic algorithm. Please, do not suggest implementations which relies on random.
- It would be great if it would support concurrency features to generate massive amounts of data

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

No one knows ...

I've created one: https://medium.com/@meiblorn/boltun-ultimate-massive-similar-text-data-generator-f952c6add37d

Feel free to submit PR's